# Finitely additive function bounded by a measure...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

have an elementary measure theory question here I can't seem to get.

Suppose $\mu$ is a a measure, and $\nu$ is a finitely additive nonnegative set function such that $\nu(A)\le \mu(A)$ for all $\mu$ measurable sets $A$. Show that $\nu$ is a measure.

Essentially, I know we have to show $\nu$ is countably additive, but nothing I'm trying is working out. I fear there is some trick here.

Comment: Are you sure this is true?

Comment: I was given this today by a professor as a "practice question," and another professor claimed that he indeed knew why it was true within minutes of looking at it. But no, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_i$ be disjoint. Consider $$\begin{align}0&\leq\nu(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\nu(A_i)&\text{}\\&=\nu(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)-\nu(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i)&\text{ by finite additivity of }\nu\\&=\nu\left(\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\right)&\text{ same reason here}\\&=\nu(\bigcup_{n+1}^{\infty}A_i)\\&<\mu(\bigcup_{n+1}^{\infty}A_i)&\text{given property}\\&=\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)-\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i)&\text{ additivity of }\mu\\&=\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu(A_i)&\text{ same here }\\&<\epsilon&\text{ }\sigma\text{-additivity of }\mu\end{align}$$

For $n>>1$.

The first inequality is from finite additivity of $\nu$. It is more clear to see that what is on the second equality is positive. Finite additivity implies monotonicity.

Comment: How do you know the first inequality/second equality are true?

Comment: I mean the first inequality also

Comment: I don't see how finite additivity gives you the second equality.

Comment: Uff. If $A\subset B$, then $0\leq\nu(B\setminus A)$. In turn $\nu(B)=\nu(B\setminus A)+\nu(A)$, by finite additivity. So $0\leq\nu(B)-\nu(A)$. *Finite additivity implies monotonicity*.

Comment: The second equality? Man, the second equality is just putting together the finitely many summands from $i=1$ to $n$ using finite additivity.

Comment: Ughh first inequality is obvious now. I completely misread it. Sorry about that. Thanks for explanation on second equality. So obvious.